# using github laravel 5.2 projects

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I tried to download larvael 5.x projects from github and tried to use it

I got these two errors :

```
Warning: require(C:\wamp\www\laravelshop\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\laravelshop\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 54

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\laravelshop\vendor/hamcrest/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\laravelshop\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 54
```

Is there anything I need to modify first after downloading any project , before using it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need `autoload.php` for library/dependency inclusion of Laravel. Please go into root directory and run `composer install` (Provided that composer is installed in your system).

Comment: i started composer install but it starts to downloading then at the end i got this error :Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned w
ith an error


  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p
lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress
] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
 [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

Comment: Can you please share your `composer.json`? Also, please share with me the GIT repo link you are using and the exact Laravel version.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add your php.exe to environment variable windows.

2) Download composer: https://getcomposer.org/download/

3) Create project typing: php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname